# Search a Google Spreadsheet and return results that are 'clickable' that takes you to the sheet and row

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrays

I have a spreadsheet with many sheets. (Data1 Data2 and Data3).
One sheet is named Search.
This search sheet will search all 3 sheets (Data1,Data2,Data3)

Results will return on the sheet named Search. Columns A, B and C will be returned under the search box. The results need to be 'clickable'.
When clicked, it takes you to the sheet and row you were searching for.

I am just trying to search across many sheets. The standard search feature in Google Sheets is not what I want.

My code:

`=QUERY(Data1!A2:C, Data2!A2:C, Data3!A2:C "SELECT * WHERE A "&E3&" '"&F3&"'")`

How do I make the results 'hyperlinks' to the sheet and row the user is looking for?

Example Page with editor permissions:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jus_FSSy4duqDpxd4Si1jov4PXfj3ilqV_gwxKuwjcE/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
=QUERY(Data1!A2:C, Data2!A2:C, Data3!A2:C "SELECT * WHERE A "&E3&" '"&F3&"'")
```

try

```
=QUERY({Data1!A2:C; Data2!A2:C; Data3!A2:C}, "SELECT * WHERE Col1 "&E3&" '"&F3&"'")
```

The above because QUERY doesn't allow multiple ranges but it could use an array.

Comment: hmm So I tried your suggestion but im getting an error on my example GoogleSheet I listed.

Comment: I'm sorry, it should be semicolons instead of commas (answer edited)

Comment: Darn, I updated with your suggestions and still no luck. I disabled my data validation drop down and still no dice.

Comment: This did work! I discovered that the search I was performing REQUIRED my typed text to be in all caps, once I did this the search worked. I need to figure out how to wrap the query to accept lower case text.

Comment: Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)